# How to get the width of the text and resize the template correspondingly?

Tags: javascript, html, css, text-size, webix

I'm trying to spread the ui.template to the width of the text. As far as I can see, there's no `autowidth` property, `adjust()` fits the container, and I don't know how to get the actual text size to apply the `resize()` property. Here's my code:

```
{
  view:"scrollview",
  scroll:"x",            
  body:{
    id:"temp",
    template:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.",
    autoheight:true,                            
  }
}
```

http://webix.com/snippet/796b80f7

Is there a way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is a getTextSize helper

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

webix.ui({  
  rows:[    
    {
      view:"scrollview",
      scroll:"x",            
      body:{
        id:"temp",
        width:webix.html.getTextSize(text).width+20,
        height: 30,
        template:text
      }
    }    
  ]  
});
```